# How to use Typescript with native ES6 Promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I'm a complete beginner to Typescript and am wondering if it's possible to use ES6 promises in Typescript and what I would have to do to get them to work. I'm running node 0.11.14 and am getting an error during compilation "Cannot find name 'Promise'"

Comment: Promises are not in Node yet, you need a package, try `es6-promise`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The current lib.d.ts doesn't have promises in it defined so you need a extra definition file for it that is why you are getting compilation errors.

You could for example use (like @elclanrs says) use the es6-promise package with the definition file from DefinitelyTyped: [es6-promise definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/index.d.ts)

You can then use it like this:

```
var p = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => { 
    resolve('a string'); 
});
```

**edit** You can use it without a definition when targeting ES6 (with the TypeScript compiler) - Note you still require the Promise to exists in the runtime ofcourse (so it won't work in old browsers :))
Add/Edit the following to your `tsconfig.json` :

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
}
```

**edit 2**
When TypeScript 2.0 will come out things will change a bit (though above still works) but definition files can be installed directly with npm like below:

`npm install --save @types/es6-promise` - [source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

**edit3**
Updating answer with more info for using the types.

Create a `package.json` file with only `{ }` as the content (if you don't have a package.json already.
Call `npm install --save @types/es6-promise` and `tsc --init`. The first npm install command will change your `package.json` to include the es6-promise as a dependency. tsc --init will create a `tsconfig.json` file for you.

You can now use the promise in your typescript file `var x: Promise<any>;`.
Execute `tsc -p .` to compile your project. You should have no errors.

Comment: many thanks Dick van den Brink! up and running after a tsd query es6-promise --action install --save

Comment: I've use your code in angular2 and there is an error: async_1.Promise is not a function. BTW I use typescript.

Comment: note that Typescript v1.7.x defines es6 promise definition file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es6.d.ts

Comment: Using that type file typescript still errors on window.Promise. I'm trying to implement a polyfil for Promise using jQuery (for IE 10). but `window.Promise = window.Promise || ...` causes an error in typescript even with the definition `///<reference path="./typings/es6-promise.d.ts" />` My target output is es5 but can use native promise if needed since the polyfill does the same.

Comment: After installing @types/es6-promise with npm, how do you include it in the .ts project? Adding it to package.json does not automatically include it in the compilation process.

Comment: @Kokodoko, I updated my answer with more detailed steps; does that help you?

Comment: Erm... but how do you include the .d.ts file in the project :) Do you need a ///ref tag or do you add it to tsconfig.json ? Also, do you need to include the index.d.ts file, or can you just include @types/es6-promise?

Comment: You don't need to include it, it happens automatically because it will pickup the package.json and notice it has 'typings' for the promise package. Are you seeing otherwise? (e.g. does the above steps don't work for you?)

Comment: I think I have the same issue as @Kokodoko - my package.json got updated after the first statement, but its not being picked up by Intellisense (I'm using VS), it transpiles and runs though so seems like a VS Intellisense issue... Any ideas on this? I already tried restoring/installing packages, but didn't make a difference.

Comment: I ran `--save @types/es6-promise` and have my type roots setup correctly in tsconfig.json. But es6-promise refuses to be included still.

Comment: Hello. I think the flag `--save-dev` should be used instead of `--save`, as the library is only used at compile time.

Comment: This is outdated. You don't have to set target to ES6 nor install a typings file. See my answer below.

Comment: In addition, I should add this line to top of the code: `import {Promise} from 'es6-promise'`. If it is not added, this error occurs: `'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Answer (score 53):

#### Alternative #1

Use the `target` and `lib` compiler options to compile directly to `es5` without needing to install the `es6-shim`. (Tested with TypeScript `2.1.4`).
In the lib section, use either `es2016` or `es2015.promise`.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es2015.promise",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

#### Alternative #2

[Use NPM to install](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/) the `es6-shim` from the [types organization](https://www.npmjs.com/~types).

```
npm install @types/es6-shim --save-dev
```

#### Alternative #3

Before TypeScript 2.0, use [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) to install the `es6-shim` globally from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

```
npm install typings --global --save-dev
typings install dt~es6-shim --global --save-dev
```

The `typings` option uses `npm` to install `typings` globally and then uses `typings` to install the shim. The `dt~` prefix means to download the shim from DefinitelyTyped. The `--global` option means that the shim's types will be available throughout the project.

## See also

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7788 - Cannot find name 'Promise' & Cannot find name 'require'

Comment: Including `es2016` is not a good idea unless your target supports ES2016. There is a lot of browsers that supports promises but not everything in ES2016. Use `es2015.promise` to include just the types for promises without pulling in types for everything in ES2016.

Comment: Don't forget to "Reload Window" in VsCode after updating this.

Answer (score 25):

As of TypeScript 2.0 you can include typings for native promises by including the following in your `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015.promise"]
}
```

This will include the promise declarations that comes with TypeScript without having to set the target to ES6.

Comment: This is the best answer, I think. It doesn't require changing your compile target or bringing in all the es2015 typings.

Comment: This is an option when you only support new browsers. If you require IE10 or older android devices support you still need a polyfill.

Answer (score 14):

If you use node.js 0.12 or above / typescript 1.4 or above, just add compiler options like:

```
tsc a.ts --target es6 --module commonjs
```

More info: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options

If you use `tsconfig.json`, then like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```

More info: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Comment: You cannot actually use commonjs and es6 together.

Comment: @AdrianBer Actually you can, things changed. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#support-for---target-es6-with---module

Comment: this won't work if you plan to support IE. You'll get 'syntax error' in the browser when running it.

Answer (score 12):

This the most recent way to do this, the above answer is outdated:

`typings install --global es6-promise`

Comment: Typings already exists for quite some time now but TypeScript 2.0 will allow installing definition files directly from npm (so you don't need an additional tool like typings). Updated my post with information when TypeScript 2.0 will become available.

Comment: We're receiving the following error: Attempted to compile "es6-promise" as a global module, but it looks like an external module. You'll need to remove the global option to continue.

Comment: now the most recent way is: npm install @type/es6-promise --save

Comment: This is no longer the most recent way. TypeScript ships with types for Promises out of the box. There is no need to install anything. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

### **Using native ES6 Promises with Typescript in Visual Studio 2015 + Node.js tools 1.2**

No npm install required as ES6 Promises is native.

**Node.js project** -> Properties -> Typescript Build tab
ECMAScript version = ECMAScript6

```
import http = require('http');
import fs = require('fs');

function findFolderAsync(directory : string): Promise<string> {

    let p = new Promise<string>(function (resolve, reject) {

        fs.stat(directory, function (err, stats) {

            //Check if error defined and the error code is "not exists"
            if (err && err.code === "ENOENT") {
                reject("Directory does not exist");
            }
            else {
                resolve("Directory exists");
            }
        });

    });
    return p;
}

findFolderAsync("myFolder").then(

    function (msg : string) {
        console.log("Promise resolved as " + msg); 
    },
    function (msg : string) {
        console.log("Promise rejected as " + msg); 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

A. If using `"target": "es5"` and TypeScript version below 2.0:

```
typings install es6-promise --save --global --source dt
```

B. If using `"target": "es5"` and TypeScript version 2.0 or higer:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015.promise"]
}
```

C. If using `"target": "es6"`, there's no need to do anything.

Comment: I'm using `"target": "es6"` with TypeScript 2.1.1 and I'm still getting `Cannot find name 'Promise'`.

Answer (score -1):

I had to downgrade `@types/core-js` to 9.36 to get it to work with `"target": "es5"` set in my tsconfig.

`"@types/core-js": "0.9.36",`

Answer (score -1):

typeorm problems
in tsconfig.json, add the following property : "strictPropertyInitialization": false

Comment: How does this resolve the problem? Please elaborate your answer.