# how to use es6-promises with typescript?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573365/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises) but having trouble getting promises to work with typescript. Hopefully we can make a clear guide.
This is for a server/node project. I'm actually using latest iojs, but targeting ES5 as output.

```
$ tsd query es6-promise --action install --save
$ npm install --save es6-promise


// typescript code:

/// <reference path="../../typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts"/>

var Promise = require("es6-promise").Promise;
require('es6-promise').polyfill();

function test():Promise {
    var p:Promise = new Promise();
    return p;
}
```

this is giving the error:

```
Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

// alternatively:

```
var p = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('a string');
});


//error=> Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.
```

What is the recommended way to return a Promise from your own node server side code?

references:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise
- https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise-commonjs-tests.ts

Answer (score 52, accepted):

main.ts

```
import {Promise} from 'es6-promise';
const p: Promise<string> = new Promise (
   (resolve: (str: string)=>void, reject: (str: string)=>void) => {
      const a: string = "hello from Promise";
      resolve(a);
   }
 );
p.then((st) => {
  console.log(st);
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es3",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noLib": false
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./main.ts",
        "./typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

compileandrun.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install es6-promise
tsd install es6-promise
tsc
node main.js
```

Comment: Is it now recommended to use `typings` rather than `tsd` ?

Comment: Note for those using Angular 2: you don't need (and shouldn't use) the import {Promise} statement, not do you need es6-promise.d.ts, as this comes bundled with the Angular 2 framework (as of beta 15, anyway).

Comment: is 'es6-promise' something that you have to download?

Comment: If you use Typescript 2+, you can specify the promise typing in tsconfig.json: ```"compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2015.promise",
            (your other libs, ex "es5" and "dom")
        ]
    }```

Comment: This generates the error: Generic type 'Promise<T>' requires 1 type argument.

Comment: `typings install --save --global dt~es6-promise` was enough with
`tsc --version` Version 2.0.3

Comment: npm install es6-promise This is enough for angular 6

Answer (score 15):

The following was on v2.1.1+ with the target set to `es5`

I was able to use Promises with `async/await` by installing `es6-promise` and then adding this to the top of the file:

```
global.Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
```

And this to `tsconfig.json`

```
"lib": [ "es2015.promise", "es5" ],
```

---

Using the `import { Promise }` form did not work for me as other libraries were crashing (ex: axios)

Answer (score 9):

I needed to polyfill this in for a different framework (specifically, axios); I didn't need to actually create my own promises, so none of these solutions worked for me.  Fortunately, the answer was simple, if well-hidden:

```
import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise'

polyfill();
```

Comment: Super belated response, but I just wanted to chime-in that yours was personally my go-to approach. TS 2.7.2 with no other framework (e.g., no Angular), the es6 promise and then `polyfill()` was the *easiest* way to support IE11. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "es6-promise": "~4.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/es6-promise": "^0.0.32"
}
```

Comment: If I do this, do I need to import `Promise` or can I just use it?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed If you do this you have to `import {Promise,} from 'es6-promise';` to use it. That’s what makes this “solution” ugly…

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any library to use promises, async/await and the rest of the new stuff and target es5. just make sure you include a lib version that supports promises, in general I use esnext - you could be more cautious..

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"], 
    "strict": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "rootDir": ".",
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

and voila, use promises and async await also:

```
async function f(url:string){
    const response = await fetch(url)
    var data = await decodeOrThrow(await response.arrayBuffer())
}
```

Comment: this question was way back in the day when io.js was a thing... seems to all work out of the box now, like you say!

Answer (score -3):

Change target to "es6" in your tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {"target": "es6" }
```

Or install TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 can also solve this problem without modify tsconfig.json

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593