# Typescript cannot find name 'Promise' despite using ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015, es6-promise

I am currently trying to develop a node.js application in Visual Studio 2015 and it keeps telling me

> TS2304 Cannot find the name 'Promise'

In the project settings I have ECMAScript 6 configured as build system and ES 2015 as module system.

I already tried

- [how to use es6-promises with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408306/how-to-use-es6-promises-with-typescript)
- [How to use Typescript with native ES6 Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573365/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises?lq=1)

without success, but in the second link they say that it should work with ECMAScript version set to 6, but it changes nothing for me.

**EDIT**: I now did some more diagnosing. The problem seems to be that there is a mismatch between the ECMAScript Versions used by IntelliSense and the build system.

I discovered this by using more ECMAScript 6 functions, which resulted in the following IntelliSense complaint:

> TS1311 Async functions are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher.

So the new question: Where do I set the ECMAScript version that IntelliSense uses?

Comment: You are using `target: "es6" `? That worked for me. When trargetting `es5` I had to use the mentioned `es6-promise` library and `import {Promise} from "es6-promise" `

Comment: Well, I have selected ECMAScript 6 in the project properties, do I need to set it somewhere else, too?

Comment: Sounds like it, I was using `tsconfig.json` with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I think I am not allowed to have a tsconfig.json file with Visual Studio. At least that is what I gather from this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3983

Comment: Hm, sorry not familiar with Visual Studio, sorry. Does it work from command line?

Comment: Yes, it does. It must then be a problem of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be an oversight (I had the same issue). You can easily make the problem go away if you install the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts) `.d.ts` files.

If you are using Nuget, just install from the Package Manager console with:

```
PM> Install-Package es6-promise.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
```

Comment: I did this via typings, but it does not help. What I now noticed is that it builds fine if I press save (compile on save is active), but if I press the Start button, the compilation fails.

Comment: @Andreas add /// <reference path="../es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts" /> at the top of your file needing Promise declaration

Comment: Should not be necessary when targeting ES6 anyways.