# TypeScript VS - compile errors but no design time errors

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig

In Visual Studio 2017, I am trying to use ES2015 Promises. Using TypeScript 2.1.5. I have a a tsconfig.json file in the solution, and it looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outFile": "outfile.js",
    "lib": [ "dom",  "es2015.promise", "es5" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

I compile, and I get typings errors, for example:

> error TS2339: Build:Property 'then' does not exist on type
>   'Promise'.

When I go to the error, I have intellisense showing it does in fact recognize the then function,and I can right click, go to definition, which takes me to lib.es2015.promise.d.ts.

Why does design time work and compile time does not, and how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

The `tsconfig.json` property called `libs` – link to dreadful official tsconfig documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) – just provides typings so that, for example, your development environment can go to the type definition, infer types and auto-complete code. It does not shim the implementation of those classes into your built-in JS code; in many cases, the target environment (eg. the browser) provides its own implementation of `Promise`, so it's unnecessary. Shimming is a responsibility left to the developer :(

Here's how to provide `Promise` which even compiles down to ES3...

### Step 1: Install a shim that provides `Promise`

In your project root, run this command (assuming you have a `package.json` there):

`npm install --save es6-promise`

### Step 2: Make it available to your code

Add this line to any `.ts` file that uses a `Promise`:

`import {Promise} from 'es6-promise';`

### Step 3: Make your `tsc` compiler aware of the typings

I'll be editing your current `tsconfig.json` file here:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // I've moved "noImplicitAny" to below.
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es3", // We can target ES3 with this method, if we want!
    "outFile": "outfile.js",

    /* From http://stackoverflow.com/a/32410515/5951226 : part of this block adds support for ES6 Promises */
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noLib": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    // "node_modules", // We'll need to include "node_modules/es6-promise", so I'll leave it to you to play around with your inclusions/exclusions which are unique to your own use case.
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

If you really do need to exclude `node_modules` (which I think is an uncommon use case – surely you can get around this..?), you can move the `es6-promise` library to a separate location and import specifically from that location instead of using the automatic module resolution.

Comment: Great info, thanks. To add some details - this is a browser app - I do have a psuedo promise shim implementation - Q.js. Packages are managed w/ bower. Typedefs are managed w/ typings.  All JS is included globally with script tags: no amd modules. I was able to get this to work by removing lib es2015.promise, include a typedef from typings - definitelytyped.  Don't know why that worked - both are typedef files. Still don't know why the compilerOptions - "lib" only worked for design time in VS and failed to work compile time,you'd think tsconfig.json compile options would be used for compiling.