# Typescript and promises in IE11

Tags: typescript, promise, internet-explorer-11, fetch

I'm working in Typescript (v2.4.2) using Webpack to compile. Everything compiles fine, but when I run my code in IE11, I get the following error: 'Promise' is undefined.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./wwwroot/js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es5",
            "scripthost",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "types": [ "es6-promise" ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./Ts/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./Ts/main.ts"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/js")
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: Infinity
        })
    ]
};
```

I understand that I need some sort of polyfill, but I'm not sure what or how to implement it. Everything I've seen so far suggests certain polyfills like Promise and Whatwg-Fetch, but whenever I add them I get compile errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promises are not supported natively in IE 11 and this has nothing to do with Typescript (Typescript libs doesn't actually adds anything to the code)

You can use [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) as Promise library

`npm install --save bluebird`

Also install types:
`npm install --save-dev @types/bluebird`

`import * as Promise from "bluebird"`

Comment: OP could albo use a polyfill instead of a separate Promise library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408306/how-to-use-es6-promises-with-typescript