# How to avoid the duplicated transformations while using babel and typescript both?

Tags: typescript, babeljs

Babel is powerful enough to transform modern code into traditional code. While Typescript can do the same thing as well. So why we need both of them? That makes me very frustrated for long.

If we firstly transforms the code with Ts, is it necessary do it agian with Babel? Is it duplicated?

Comment: What forces you to use Babel if you have typescript?

Comment: That Typescript can't do but Babel can forces me to use Babel. @@

Comment: Babel can `polyfill` Promise, but Ts can't. But why not Typescript supports all the features what Babel has?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408306/how-to-use-es6-promises-with-typescript

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking. It sounds like you're asking if you need Babel, or why you need Babel, but your comment demonstrates that you know why. So what do you want to know?

Comment: I think there are some duplicated things both babel and typescript can do. Only Ts is enough if Ts can do everything that babel can. Do Ts & Babel share some features?