# Typescript Firebase definition file, Promises

Tags: typescript, firebase

I am trying to use promises with Firebase in Typescript using this definition file: https://www.nuget.org/packages/firebase.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/
But I am getting this error trying to use promises: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.` I guess it is because the definition files does not support Promises right ? I am just starting getting Typescript to know, can anyone tell me how I can change the definition file to support promises ?

Comment: The current firebase typings don't appear to contain any Promises, probably best to wait for someone else to update them.

Comment: It looks like the definitions file needs to be updated, yes. This would be a conversation best taken up with the author of the package (too bad it's not on GitHub or somewhere with an issue tracker).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this, definition file for Firebase has supported Promise:
[firebase.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/73fa26213aa5d2e1de5d7c2cc74118108cb2e5fa/firebase/firebase.d.ts)

However, you will still need to either install es6-promise package, or configure tsc for ES6. More detail can be found at other SO question:
[How to use Typescript with native ES6 Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573365/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises)

Comment: If I do this: typings install --global es6-promise I get this error: Attempted to compile "es6-promise" as a global module, but it looks like an external module. You'll need to remove the global option to continue.