# How to include files from definitely typed in an Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm working on an angular 2/node.js app and I'm currently trying to install the typings for the project. Previously when I would run the server and start the typscript compilerm I would get the following log:

```
bash-3.1$ npm start

> support-dashboard@1.0.0 start c:\MEAN_project
> concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "node server.js"

[1] Magic happens on port 8080
[0]
[0] > support-dashboard@1.0.0 tsc:w c:\MEAN_project
[0] > tsc -w
[0]
[0] node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts(78,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(38,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(92,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(151,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(23,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(25,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(103,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(103,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(8,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(12,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(59,148): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(100,144): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(105,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(106,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(71,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts(75,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(85,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] 8:52:59 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

I searched online and found that I could use the typings CLI tool in order install the typings definitions; however I was getting errors when I tried to install packages from my typings.json file through postinstall.

I saw that an alternative was to use the [definitely typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) library from github and copied es6-promise.d.ts from definitely typed and added it to the root of my project and ran the server again as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110763/cannot-find-name-promise-despite-using-es6-promise-d-ts). This time, the messages about Promise not being found went away.

What I haven't been able to figure out is which .ts files contain definitions for 'Map' , 'Set', and 'Map constructor'. **Which files should I be including in order to enable the typescript compilers to find these libraries?**

Answer (score 1):

If the library does not include typings, you can install them using npm:

```
npm install d3 --save
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
```

[Quoted from the angular-cli documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation)

[@types](https://www.npmjs.com/~types) in npm contains all the [definitely typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) type definitions.