# Using es6-promise with TypeScript 2.1 ES5 Webpack (async/await)

Tags: typescript, promise, webpack, async-await, ecmascript-5

I try to use `es6-promise` with TypeScript 2.1.1 targeting ES5 and webpack.

**app.ts**

```js
import "es6-promise/auto";

export class Foo {
    bar() : Promise<string>{
        return Promise.resolve("baz");
    }
}
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './app.ts',
    },

    output: {
        path: 'dist/ie',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader']
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [  
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Promise: 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.Promise!es6-promises'
        }),

    ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "ieArtifactName": "foo",
  "version": "3.0.0-1",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "src/app.ts",
  "author": {
    "name": "...",
    "email": "...",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.32",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.7.34",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "es6-promise-promise": "^1.0.0",
    "es6-promises": "^1.0.10",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "=2.2.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.14",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.2",
    "node-static": "^0.7.9",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.0.9",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

I start webpack using the command line

```
webpack --config config/webpack.common.js
```

The behavior is the following:

- Webstorm 2016.3.1 highlights everything fine.
- compiler runs
- compiler shows 2 errors

  > ERROR in [default] D:...\app.ts:4:16 
  >   Cannot find name 'Promise'.

I tried `es6-promise`, `es6-promises`, `es6-promise-promise`and a bunch of import expressions.

When I add `import {Promise} from "es6-promise"` webstorm highlights it as unused import but the error is gone. Is it possible to use Promises targeting ES5 without import? Because after changing the target to ES6 I'd have to touch every file and remove the import.

### Problems with async

My goal is to be able to use async/await, because I'm used to it from C# and I hate the callback hell. If I change the code to

```
export class Foo {
    async bar() : Promise<string>{
        return "baz";
    }
}
```

The compiler complains again

> Cannot find name 'Promise'.

Adding the import `import {Promise} from "es6-promise";` makes it even worse.

> Duplicate identifier 'Promise'. Compiler reserves name 'Promise' in top level scope of a module containing async functions.

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573365/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises

Comment: Hmm one comment of the answer helped. Adding the reference to the typing in app.ts helped. `///<reference path="../node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts" />`. I don't have to import it in any file.

Comment: You should also do: 
entry: {
    'es6-promise',    
    'app': './app.ts',
  },

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the TypeScript compiler aware of ES2015 promises by adding `"es2015.promise"` to the list of library files to include in your *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es5",
            "scripthost",
            "es2015.promise"
        ]
    }
}
```

Native promises were only introduced in ES2015 and are not available in ES5, which you're targeting. That's why the TypeScript compiler says it can't find the name `Promise`. Since you're providing a polyfill, there will be a `Promise` at runtime. The above solution makes TypeScript aware of that.

**Edit Sven-Michael**

You don't even need provide `Promise` via provide plugin. You just need to `import "es6-promise/auto";`

Comment: i think this is an incorrect solution. true typescript will aware of ES6 promise. but still the compiler target is ES5. when we are using the compiled script on ES5 browser, we will got error `Promise` not found.

Comment: The key part here is _"Since you're providing a polyfill, there will be a Promise at runtime."_ TypeScript doesn't polyfill `Promise` itself; therefore, _you_ need to provide a polyfill so that `Promise` will be available at runtime even in older browsers. The `lib` compiler option only tells TypeScript that it can expect to have a working `Promise` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use es6-promise polyfill. You can reference it in the following way (Typescript + Webpack2):

```
entry: {
    'es6-promise',    
    'app': './app.ts',
}
```