# jasmine.Promise vs webdriver.promise.Promise

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor

Have this method in a `Protractor` page object test:

```
public navigateTo = (): Promise<any> => {
    return browser.get('https://material.angular.io/');
};
```

Want to define the type that is returned i.e. `Promise<any>`.

Should I import the `jasmine` promise? Or the `webdriver` promise?

```
import * as webdriver from "selenium-webdriver";
import Promise = webdriver.promise.Promise;
```

or

```
import Promise = jasmine.Promise;
```

I'm confused about why I need to specify an implementation of promise. Can I specify an interface for `Promise`?

---

edit: What I really wanted to do was:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/es6-promise
```

This gave me the `Promise<any>` type.

Relevant Question: [How to use Typescript with native ES6 Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573365/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises#27573589/)

Comment: what's the problem with ES6 Promise and why don't you use it instead?

Comment: I get a `TSError: Unable to compile TypeScript
practice.e2e-spec.ts : Cannot find name 'Promise'` 

So maybe I can use ES6 promise, but I don't have a type for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Importing `webdriver.promise.Promise`**

Most API calls to selenium-webdriver return a `webdriver.promise.Promise`. These promises are executed in order via the control flow. Recently they have switched from their own implementation of promises to native ES6 style promises.

Do you need to import `webdriver.promise.Promise` into your Protractor test? Probably not.

**Importing `jasmine.Promise`**

`jasmine.Promise` does not come from the jasmine typings but it comes from the `jasminewd2` typings. This is a helper to get the rest of the typings to work. Should you import `jasmine.Promise` to your test? Absolutely no.

**Protractor appears synchronous**

My argument that you do not need to import `webdriver.promise.Promise` is that Protractor helps synchronize the promises. You do not need to know the result of `browser.get(URL)`. It is a promise and that is done for you. So the only reason why you want to import this, is if you are creating a new `webdriver.promise.Promise`.

Also, I like to import webdriver promises like:

```
import {promise as wdpromise} from 'selenium-webdriver'

let wpromise = new wdpromise.Promise(resolveCallback, rejectCallback);

// a native promise
let npromise = new Promise(resolveCallback, rejectCallback);
```

I would avoid importing as `Promise` since it is also how you create native ES6 promises. See above.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much. I would like `navigateTo`'s return type to be `Promise<any>`. I've found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573365/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises#27573589/. This is probably why I'm confused. I came to my answer because Intellij prompted me to import those types when I defined return type `Promise<any>`.

Comment: Ended up doing `npm install --save @types/es6-promise`. That is what I wanted, but I did not understand what I wanted when I asked the question :). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Regarding `jasmine.Promise`, this was changed in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/d131a79ae894f23d26b8fac5859f040853ae2817 and not the global `Promise` is used.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm glad this is getting cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on TypeScript to answer your second question - `I'm confused about why I need to specify an implementation of promise.` But I can answer the first part of it

`Should I import the jasmine promise? Or the webdriver promise?`

Different Protractor commands return a promise of different type - But mostly it is `webdriver.promise.Promise`. The source of truth for this information is the [Protractor API docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api)

Some examples

```
         sendKeys() - webdriver.promise.Promise.<void>
         executeScript() - promise.Promise<T>
         getText() - webdriver.promise.Promise.<string>
         restart() - webdriver.promise.Promise<ProtractorBrowser>
         isPresent() - Promise<boolean>
```

`browser.get()` returns a `webdriver.promise.Promise`