# import resolve and reject function types from TypeScript definitions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a function, and I pass resolve and reject to it:

```
resolve: Function, reject: Function
```

aka:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   helper(resolve,reject);
})
```

I am looking for the type definitions for these two functions (I know they are simple, but I might as well use the official ones).

I see this question/answers:
[How to use Typescript with native ES6 Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573365/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises)

but unfortunately, none of them mention the actual definition to use, anyone know?

Comment: You could just open your favorite TS editor and get the type

Comment: This is what I got: `resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of promise constructor is:

```
declare type PromiseConstructorLike = 
    new <T>(executor: 
        (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, 
         reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) => PromiseLike<T>;
```

You can copy the same.